# SQL запрос для перевода столбца из cp1251 в utf8

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, кодировка, phpmyadmin

В БД необходимо перевести столбец таблицы из кодировки cp1251 в utf8. Читал на форумах, что cp1251 конвертируют в байты и в этом же запросе, обратно в utf8. Как написать такой sql запрос?

Comment: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN

Comment: @Akina , как это поможет поменять кодировку?

Comment: @EugeneKotov Это поможет найти соответствующий пункт в справке, а затем набрать  ALTER TABLE `tablename` modify COLUMN `columnname` COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Дело в том, что у меня там крокозяблики и такой запрос переведёт их в очередную кашу. Я находил запросы с функциями CAST и CONVERT, но теперь не могу найти ничего подобного.

Comment: Ну тогда добавьте новое поле с требуемой кодировкой, а потом обновите его из старого с использованием CONVERT()...

Comment: @Akina , спасибо за ответ. Попробовал создать какую же таблицу но с другой кодировкой и занести туда этот столбец ( CONVERT(setting_value USING utf8) setting_value ). Но в новой таблице вместо старых крокозябликов появились вопросы.

Comment: *в новой таблице вместо старых крокозябликов появились вопросы.* Вы смотрели через UTF8-консоль или как? если иначе - то напрасно, между данными и отображением у Вас происходит несколько конвертаций, к тому же не всеми, возможно, Вы сможете управлять...

Comment: @Akina , тогда я не понимаю, почему на сайт данные всё равно отображаются как в первоначальном варианте? с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: *почему на сайт данные всё равно отображаются как в первоначальном варианте?* Да потому что данные из таблицы до отображения на сайте переконвертируются не один раз... и первый раз, вероятно, ещё на MySQL-сервере в соответствии с настройками соединения... а конечный формат там, как и вся цепочка дальше, не изменился же ж...